# Proving van Emde Boas recurrence

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques, recurrence-relation, master-theorem, van-emde-boas-trees

I have tried to solve the following question:

> **van Emde Boas Bounds** Show that $T(u) = T(\sqrt{u}) + O(1)$ has the solution $T(u) = O(\log\log u)$. *Hint:* consider the binary representation of $u$.

In CLRS (Introduction to Algorithms), they make use of the master method case 2. They let $m = \log_2u$ so we have $T(2^m) = T(2^{m/2}) +O(1)$. Then they substitute $T(2^m) = S(m)$ and the recurrence looks as follows:

$$S(m) = S(m/2) + O(1).$$

The above confuses me, because I don't see how $S(m/2)$ is the same as $T(2^{m/2})$. Taking half of $m$ is not the same as taking half of the exponent $m$.

Comment: If $S(m) = T(2^m)$ for all $m$, then $S(m/2) = T(2^{m/2})$.

Comment: it does not make sense, if you take half om m (i.e. $m/2$) you don't get the same as $2^{m/2}$. Fx: $2^{log_216/2} = 4$ but $log_216/2 = 8$.

Comment: You can try it out in python. Let's say that $S(m) = 2^m$, i.e. `def S(m): return 2**m`. Then $S(8) = 256 = 2^8$ and $S(8/2) = 16 = 2^{8/2}$. Try it out!

Comment: @GoldenRetriever: I believe you're interpreting $log_2 16 / 2$ inconsistently. $(log_2 16) / 2 \not= log_2 (16 / 2$)$.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to *define* a new function $S(m)$ by $S(m) = T(2^m)$. Then *by definition* we have $S(m/2) = T(2^{m/2}) = T(\sqrt{2^m})$.

Comment: So we are allowed to say that $S(m/2) = T(2^{m/2})$ even though, algebraically, it's not the same? But why is that the case? How can we make a proof on something we invent?

Comment: In fact, algebraically it is the case. *By definition*, $S(a) = T(2^a)$. That's how we define $S$. You can substitute anything for $a$, using the principle of substitution of equals-by-equals.

Comment: You ask why we are allowed to invent things. The master theorem states that if a function $f$ satisfies condition such-and-such, then it has so-and-so asymptotics. It applies to any function, for example to the function $S$ given by the formula $S(m) = T(2^m)$.